# set NSDate in object

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, nsdate

I have an object, `SCHRss` which has a `NSDate` to be set in the header file. The code looks like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate * time;
```

I want to create a `SCHRss` object and set the `NSDate`. At the moment the code looks like this:

```
SCHRss *rssObject = [[SCHRss alloc] init];

[rssObject setTitle:self.title];
[rssObject setLink:self.link];
[rssObject setImage:self.image];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE, d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss zzzz"];
[dateFormat setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
[rssObject setTime:[dateFormat dateFromString:self.time]];

[self.feeds addObject:rssObject];
```

`self.time` is returning the correct value. But when I called `[rssObject time]` from the console, `nil` is being returned. Any ideas?

For reference, the time stamp looks like this: `Tue, 16 Jun 2015 06:41:58 +0000`

Comment: Your date format doesn't actually match the time stamp string. Use the proper date format.

Comment: Seems to work on `self.date`. What would be the proper format then?

Comment: Look at the spec for the date format specifiers. You have the three-letter weekday in your timestamp. But you use `EEEE`. Look at what the spec says for weekday formatting. Do the same for each and every part. Also note that you will probably need to set the formatter's locale to the special locale of `en_US_POSIX` if your timestamps are always going to be in English. If you don't the code will fail for any user not using English.